# Passing back a UpdatePanel from a method is not updating

Tags: c#, asp.net, updatepanel

The following code does not update the contents of the UpdatePanel during an asynchronous callback:

```
    protected void getMoreInfoCommand_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        UpdatePanel updatePanel = (UpdatePanel)button.Parent.Parent;

        updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Clear();

         switch(e.CommandName)
         {
            case "PERSON":
                 Person.Portal.UserProfile userProfile = new Person.Portal.UserProfile(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                 updatePanel = getPanel(userProfile, true);
                 break;
         }
    }

   protected UpdatePanel getPanel(object obj, bool more)
    {
        UpdatePanel updatePanel = new UpdatePanel();
        updatePanel.UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional;
        updatePanel.EnableViewState = true;
        updatePanel.ViewStateMode = System.Web.UI.ViewStateMode.Enabled;
        updatePanel.ChildrenAsTriggers = true;
        StringBuilder htmlBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        switch (obj.GetType().ToString().Trim())
        {
            case "Person.Portal.UserProfile":
                Person.Portal.UserProfile userProfile = (Person.Portal.UserProfile)obj;
                htmlBuilder.Append("<TABLE border='1' cellpadding=3 cellspacing=0 width=20%>");

                htmlBuilder.Append("<tr><td colspan=2>");
                htmlBuilder.Append("<font color='gray' size=2>Person</font>");
                updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(htmlBuilder.ToString()));
                htmlBuilder.Length = 0;

                Button morePersonButton = new Button();
                morePersonButton.ID = "morePersonButton";
                morePersonButton.Text = "More";
                morePersonButton.CommandName = "PERSON";
                morePersonButton.CommandArgument = userProfile.ID;
                morePersonButton.Command += new CommandEventHandler(getMoreInfoCommand_Click);

                updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(morePersonButton);

                htmlBuilder.Append("<tr><td align='center' colspan=2>");
                htmlBuilder.Append("<img src='https://webadvisor.oc.edu/pictures/");
                htmlBuilder.Append(userProfile.Pic_ID);
                htmlBuilder.Append(".jpg'>");
                htmlBuilder.Append("</tr>");

                htmlBuilder.Append("<tr><td>");
                htmlBuilder.Append("<B>Name</B><TD>");
                htmlBuilder.Append(userProfile.FirstName + " " + userProfile.LastName);
                htmlBuilder.Append("</tr>");

                htmlBuilder.Append("<tr><td>");
                htmlBuilder.Append("<B>Email Address</B><TD>");
                htmlBuilder.Append(userProfile.EmailAddress);
                htmlBuilder.Append("</tr>");

                htmlBuilder.Append("<tr><td>");
                htmlBuilder.Append("<B>Phone</B><TD>");
                htmlBuilder.Append(userProfile.Phone);
                htmlBuilder.Append("</tr>");                    

                if (more)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(userProfile.Office_Number))
                    {
                        htmlBuilder.Append("<tr><td>");
                        htmlBuilder.Append("<B>Office Building</B><TD>");
                        htmlBuilder.Append(userProfile.Office_Number);
                        htmlBuilder.Append("</tr>");    
                    }
                }

                htmlBuilder.Append("</TABLE><BR>");

                updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(htmlBuilder.ToString()));

                htmlBuilder.Length = 0;
                break;
        }
        return updatePanel;
    }
```

However if I do the following it works:

```
    protected void getMoreInfoCommand_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
    {
        Button button = (Button)sender;
        UpdatePanel updatePanel = (UpdatePanel)button.Parent.Parent;

        updatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Clear();

         switch(e.CommandName)
         {
            case "PERSON":
                 Person.Portal.UserProfile userProfile = new Person.Portal.UserProfile(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                 getPanel(userProfile, true, ref updatePanel);
                 break;
         }
    }


    protected void getPanel(object obj, bool more, ref UpdatePanel updatePanel) 
    { 
        ...
    }
```

I use getPanel() elsewhere and don't really want to change the way it works.  I don't understand why the first example does not work.  What am I missing?  Is there a workaround?

Comment: What does getPanel() look like before and after the code changes?

Comment: In the first example I create a new UpdatePanel and return it.  In the second example I pass in the UpdatePanel by reference and add the controls that way.

Comment: please post at least an anonymized version of getPanel method.. its not worth looking at this questions otherwise.

Comment: OK I added most of the code for getPanel() to the first example.  I already explained the only difference in my previous comment so I am not going to add the same code to the second example.

Answer (score 0):

The update panel was already rendered, you will have to replace the Update Panel from it's parent's controls collection. Changing the controls collection of the Update Panels parent will update it correctly.